# Spaces in C macro expansion when running in docker bash

Tags: c, bash, docker

I hit a strange issue when compiling a source file with docker.

When I launch a docker container and execute the gcc compiler from the bash shell, it works as expected (simplified version):

```
> docker run -it myImage bash
root@3ce7dbe42569:/# gcc main.c
```

However, when I invoke it as follows

```
> docker run -it myImage bash -l -c gcc main.c
```

I get

```
fatal error: 'linux / mymodule _ linux .h' file not found

note: expanded from macro 'TARGET_INCLUDE'
#define TARGET_INCLUDE(module) STR(IDENT(PLATFORM) IDENT(/) IDENT(module) IDENT(_) IDENT(PLATFORM) IDENT(.h))
```

The spaces in the include file shouldn't be there.

Anyone?

Comment: Are you saying that the `#define` directive reported in the error message is different from the real `#define` directive in your source?

Comment: ...because the spaces definitely should not be in the `#define` directive. The whole point of the `IDENT` macro is to be able to write the file path without spaces between the components. So if you put them there, remove them. If the compiler inserted them behind your back, then something weird  is going on.

Comment: @rici I removed the spaces. That solved the issue with the spaces but then I hit another issue that I don't see when compiling on my native machine or in a bash shell inside the docker. Eventually, I found a way in which the behaviour is identical between the three flavours.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem:

Add following line to `Dockerfile`

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
```

and invoke docker as follows:

```
docker run -it myImage "gcc main.c"
```

(still don't understand the root cause)